# How to import Joomla! JFactory from within custom file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm trying to use `$db = JFactory::getDbo();` in a new file I created, but it doesn't seem to work, it tells me JFactory is not defined, and I can't seem to get it to work, I've tried importing a lot of libraries and stuff and no success so far.
Will post the code tomorrow morning when I reach work, but I'm basically calling an AJAX function from jquery, to this new php file I created, just trying to pass some stuff to the database. 
I don't really want to spend a lot of time creating a component or such to make it work, even tho it's safer. Does anyknow know how I can access the JFactory class from this file?

EDIT: In the JS code i use JQuery to send an AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: './templates/casacomigo/scripts/ajax.php',
  data: { json: json },
  success:function(html) {
  alert(html);
  }
});
```

then, in the php file:

```
<?php
  define('_JEXEC', 1);
  define( 'JPATH_BASE', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
  define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/casacomigo/libraries/import.php'); // framework
  require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/casacomigo/configuration.php'); // config file
  require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/casacomigo/includes/defines.php');
  $json = ($_POST['json']);
  print_r($json);

  $db = JFactory::getDbo();

  ...
?>
```

In that moment when i do $db = JFactory::getDbo(); i get the error: 
Class 'JFactory' not found

Answer (score 0):

Which Joomla version are you using?

Try adding `require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';` after `require_once(JPATH_BASE . '/casacomigo/includes/defines.php');`